# JQuery if statement with selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For jquery can you do something like this:
 HTML:

```
    <div class = "div" id="one"> <\div>
    <div class = "div" id="Two"> <\div>
```

Jquery:

```
     .onclick function for class .div
      { 
           if ($('#one')) //is selected
           { 
                    do this
            } 
           else if ($('#two'))
           {
                    do this
           }
```

Comment: Do you have a real attempt or are you just posting pseudocode

Comment: Why don't you bind those two elements separately with something `$("#one").on('click', function(){});` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinking of this

```js
$('body').on('click','.test',function () {
  
  if ( this.id === 'one' ) {
      alert('Click one');
    }
  if ( this.id === 'two' ) {
      alert('Click two');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="test" id="one">One</div>
<div class="test" id="two">Two</div>
</body>
```

Alternate

```js
$('.test').click(function () {
  
  if ( this.id === 'one' ) {
      alert('Click one');
    }
  if ( this.id === 'two' ) {
      alert('Click two');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="test" id="one">One</div>
<div class="test" id="two">Two</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I wouldnt want to make my bidy into onclick. Can i just give both divs the same class name and then use the onclick function with the class name and use if else statement like i have in op selecting specific ids = true?

Comment: use '$('.test').onclick(...)` with same function body will work also

Comment: Yes thank you, that is exactly what i wanted to confirm

Comment: Would this work if you had a div wrapper around thise two divs? Such as

Comment: Would this work if you had a div you appened one of these divs to?  Such as <div class = "append"></div><div id ="one"><\div><div id ="two"><\div>Then in jquery do something like: if ($(.append#one)) {do this} else if ($(.append#two)){do this}

Comment: each of the divs #one and #two have different numbers and that matters. So i was wondering if you could somehow do an if statement to check if a div has a another div with an id appended in it, if so you do the code else if its another div with another id do code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
$('#one').click(function() {
  //do this
});
$('#two').click(function() {
  //do this
});
```

If both `div`s have same `class`

```
$('.classname#one').click(function() {
  //do this
});
$('.classname#two').click(function() {
  //do this
});
```

If you want to restrict this to `div`s

```
$('div.classname#one').click(function() {
  //do this
});
$('div.classname#two').click(function() {
  //do this
});
```

Comment: Well the thing is this is related to a game. And their attach powers differ. So if a specific opponent is in lets say div A then he will need to do x amount of damage. Same for your player picked. So i was thinking about giving them all same class name but different id's. Use class name for onlick function and id's in if statement, but will this work?

Comment: yes, `if (this.id === '...')` inside common handler

Comment: If your document only contains one element with the id `one` and `two`, then yes